# Mongo DB write and Read sync

Tags: mysql, mongodb, transactions, atomic

Recently I observed that My application that is supposed to write only 100 rows, wrote 102 rows in individual writes. (into Mongo DB)

I am confused, if I write a row to mongo db, and the flush has not happened yet. At that time if I do a read on the number of rows written, will it include the row not yet flushed?

What would be a more robust and atomic way of implementing a finite ticket purchase system? (preferably using mongo db, because the data is schema less. I am ready to resort to a combination of mongo db and mysql for transaction feature of mysql)

Comment: What `writeConcern` are you using ? Are you reading from the primary ar secondary server ?

Comment: I am not using any special setting. Infact I am new with mongodb. So I am yet to discover the best practises.

Comment: I am on local machine. No sharding activated.

Comment: My basic doubt is - before flushing the data to db, if I make a read from db, would db consider the data in-memory which is not flushed, and return that too.